# Does an InterruptException cause the thread to stop

Tags: java, multithreading

I thought that the currently executing Thread will be stooped if the exception is thrown. Bu when I was going throught a java test a came across with the question:

> Under which conditions will a currently executing thread stop?
>
> 1. When an interrupted exception occurs.
> 2. When a thread of higher priority is ready (becomes runnable).
> 3. When the thread creates a new thread.
> 4. When the stop() method is called.
>
> A. 1 and 3
>
> B. 2 and 4
>
> C. 1 and 4
>
> D. 2 and 3

The right answer was `B`, but what then happens if the exception is thrown? I thought the thread is terminating.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The right answer was B

No it wasn't. *None* of the answers given is correct.

> but what then happens if the exception is thrown? I thought the thread is terminating.

No. The thread catches `InterruptedException` from whatever method it was calling that can throw it, for example `Thread.sleep()`. If it doesn't call such a method, nothing happens at all.

Answer (score 2):

When a method throws InterruptedException, it is telling that it is a *blocking method* and that it will make an attempt to unblock and return early -- if you ask nicely.

When you try to interrupt a thread by calling interrupt() on the thread instance, it merely sends a signal. It depends on the actual thread to respond to that signal. Methods like Thread.sleep() and Object.wait() can look for this signal and make an attempt to stop what it is doing and return early and ***indicate its early return*** by throwing InterruptedException. So it's usually an acknowledgement from some blocking methods to the interrupt() request sent by some other thread.

```
        Thread t = new Thread(() -> {
             try {
                 Thread.sleep(5000); // Thread.sleep() allows a cancellation mechanism
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("interrupted by some one else from outside");
            }
         });

         t.start();
         try {
            t.interrupt();
            t.join(); // waiting for the thread to finish its execution
            System.out.println("back in main");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("interrupted");
        }
```

Output :

```
interrupted by some one else from outside
back in main
```

But if you have thread like this

```
       Thread t = new Thread(() -> {
             try {
                 for(int i=0;i<1_000_000;i++){
                     System.out.println(i);
                 }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("interrupted by some one else from outside");
            }
       });
```

Calling interrupt() on above thread will not do anything useful because we're not looking for the signal, so thread will print all numbers and join the main thread as if nobody ever asked it to stop doing what it is doing.

In case you want to learn more about this InterruptedException, I highly recommend [this](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp05236/#2.0)Brian Goetz's article from IBM Developer Works

Answer (score 1):

A thread, `t`, will stop if some other thread calls `t.stop()`, but *please* don't ever do that!  One thread should never *force* another thread to do anything.  Threads should always cooperate.  Any program that calls t.stop() is very likely to contain bugs that you won't be able to fix without getting rid of the stop() call.

A thread will *terminate* (which is a kind of stop, right?) if some external process kills the JVM.

A *daemon thread* will terminate if the JVM shuts down because there are no non-daemon threads left to keep it alive.

A thread may stop or terminate because of the action of an attached debugger.

The only other reason why a thread will stop (and terminate) is if its `run()` method *completes*.  A method can either complete *normally* by returning, or it can terminate *abnormally* (i.e., an exception is thrown *and not caught* within the method call.)  A thread will terminate if its run() method completes in either way.

An InterruptedException doesn't affect a thread any differently from any other exception.  If the thread catches the exception, then the thread will continue to run, <strike>but if no method in the thread catches it, then the thread's run() method will abnormally complete, and the thread will terminate (stop).</strike>

Comment: `InterruptedException` is checked. Somebody has to catch it when a method that throws it is called. Otherwise the program does not compile. It can't propagate out of the `run()` method as you describe.

Comment: @EJP, Hmm...  Good point.  Well, OK then,   `InterruptedException` doesn't affect a thread any differently from any _checked_ exception, which means that it can _not_, in and of itself, cause a thread to stop..